# Autohotkey get user domain variable

Tags: variables, dns, autohotkey, var

I'm wondering that there's no %userdomain% variable analog in Autohotkey.
I've found some info about the registry-using-solution but maybe there's some other ways?

There's a lot of variables such as "A_Username" included in AHK but nothing for the domain info.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found using google in less than a min..

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/77940-detect-current-windows-domain/

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much! I've missed that topic ;-) 
Although it is bound to the computer, and the user may be outside the domain

Comment: You are welcome. I also found this, seems to have some more Domain stuff and you might be interested in some of this code here: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/78088-administration-tool-for-windowsdomains/

Answer (score 1):

This should answer that question:

```
EnvGet, V, USERDOMAIN
Msgbox % V
```

Comment: It looks like there's no need to invoke `EnvGet`. You can directly do `MsgBox % USERDOMAIN`.